# how to find td class=name from a button?

Tags: jquery

How do I find the name in the  when the button is clicked. Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philphil/mnasL80h/)
I can't get `name=` to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn.del-attendee').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            name= $(this).closest('tr').find('td.name').text;

            alert(name);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include parentheses as `text()` is a method, not a property (in jQuery)

```
name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.name').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

this works too:

```
name= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
```